# Preloading webchunks based on route in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

When I build my VueJs application, it automatically imports the app.js and chunk-vendor.js files with the preload attribute. This is great as it speeds up the page load time of my application.

I've looked at `@vue/preload-webpack-plugin` and I can see that I can preload specific webchunks or assets. This has the effect of preloading those files on all routes.

The thing I would really like to do is preload webchunks based on the initial route that is loaded (the first route the user visits).

Lets say I have two routes; home and accounts. Both of these routes are lazy loaded. When a user opens /home as their first page, I would like to preload the js and css webchunks related to the homepage. If the user initially opens the /accounts page, I would like to preload the webchunks related to the accounts page.

Its not possible to use wildcards in preload statements, so I know I can't do this statically.

Any ideas of how this could work? Has anyone heard of such a project being suggested elsewhere?

EDIT: Something I tried as an experiment was injecting preload headers into my index.html file using the beforeRouteEnter method. Whilst I could see the preload header in my DOM, I found that browsers did not observe the header in time, so the image I was experimenting with was not pre-loaded. In any case, this wouldn't have worked for a dynamically named file, but useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

With SSR it is possible and framework like Nuxt does it automatically, because it builds separate html file for each route. So this html can be "tailored" for this specific route and include/preload all the code route needs...

Without SSR it much harder. `@vue/preload-webpack-plugin` works by injecting `preload` links into the `index.html` at build time and since there is only one `index.html` for a whole app, you can't make it route dependent (with this plugin). So what Vue CLI does is prefetching all the async chunks [by default](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch) (clearly preferring speed over bandwidth usage)

I can imagine a solution in the form of Webpack plugin, which replaces `preload-webpack-plugin` and instead of generating preload/prefetch links at build time just generates some inline script with the map of "route name => chunk name" (some well defined naming convention would be needed) that would inject the links dynamically to the DOM base on the current URL. But even with my "googling skills" I wasn't able to find anything like that...

Comment: I didn't know Nuxt does that, so very useful info, thanks. I have been considering prerendering my application so this is another reason to consider that option.